# MediaProvider: User 10536 does not have read permission on file android 11

Tags: android

i had this problem, im trying to list all files on folder using storage access framework and media store api but i got this error "MediaProvider: User 10536 does not have read permission on file "

my app works fine if i use manage all files, but due to google policies i had to remove this permison on my app, but cant find way to do it in android 11

can some one helpme please

```
fun opendd(){
 val i=Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
    flags=Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
}
startActivityIfNeeded(i, 33)
    }


 //on result
  33 -> {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            data?.data?.also { uri ->
               

                val dfile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(applicationContext, uri)
                val fileList = dfile!!.listFiles()
                Log.d("usr", fileList.toString())
                val jj = 1
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
                    
                    //se inicia un activity para mostrar la imagen en este caso
                    val i = Intent(this, AnimatedImageView::class.java)
                    i.data=  MediaStore.getMediaUri( this,fileList[9].uri)
                    startActivity(i)

                }
                }
              
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `flags=Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` Renove that flag. It has no effect.

Comment: It is unclear why you wanna convert a saf uri to a media store uri.

Comment: Further it is unclear what you wanna do with the resulting uri.

Comment: Try to use the saf uri first in the same activity

Comment: You apply startActivity for every file in the listing.

Comment: I will try, i use startactivity because it is webp visor, when you touch any img it will promp and enlarge, I need list all files on some folders, i dont know what is saf uri and media uri diferences, i dont know how to use saf uri